# How to rename a file using wstring?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

How can I rename a file in c++?

```
rename(tempFileName.c_str(), tempFileName.c_str()+"new.txt");
```

But `tempFileName` is of type `std::wstring`. But `rename()` functions accepts only `const char*` parameters.

Comment: `tempFileName.c_str() + "new.txt"` is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When working with `Visual Studio`, you usually work with wide-strings. In order to rename the file you can use `MoveFileEx`-function, you can rename the file like this.

```
std::wstring newFilename = tempFileName.c_str();
newFilename += _T("new.txt");
if(!MoveFileEx(tempFileName.c_str(), newFilename.c_str(), flags )){
//error handling if call fails
}
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365240%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the documentation.

Comment: `MoveFileEx` demands a `const (w)char*`. LPTCSTR is defined as `const char*`, though I agree it might be little difficult using temporary objects.

Comment: @bash.d Please ensure you post correct content next time. This should be expected from someone with nearly 2k rep

Comment: OK.  Debugging 101:  if something strange is happening, split up the problem.  You are assembling a fileSpec, so you might have introduced a 'fileSpec' temporary and assembled the spec into that before attempting the rename.  When inspecting the temp with a debugger, you would have seen that it was incorrect.

Answer (score 9):

In Visual C++, the wide-character version of rename() is _wrename(). This isn't portable, but you may not care about that. Also, you can't add raw string pointers like that, you want something like this (not tested):

```
std::wstring newName(tempFileName);
newName += L"new.txt";
_wrename(tempFileName.c_str(), newName.c_str());
```

Comment: Just tried a quick example and it works here. At a guess either the file you're renaming from doesn't exist, or the file you're renaming to already exists - time to do some debugging.

Comment: It's notable that EPIPE is defined as 32, which is also the value of the Windows error code ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION ("The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.") This is most likely the cause of it not working for you - you've got the file open elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are targeting Windows, use the [`_wrename()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw5t957f%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) function instead.